# Laravel database table is not updating using Query Builder

Tags: laravel

I have feeds table in shibbir_DB3 database. In this table I have a column called `status`. I am trying to update this `status` column but it's not updating.

What I am using is this:

```
// Get the databae name from projects table
        $get_db_name = DB::table('projects')
        ->leftJoin('mysql_servers', 'mysql_servers.id_mysql_server', '=', 'projects.id_mysql_server')
        ->leftJoin('project_users', 'project_users.id_project', '=', 'projects.id_project')
        ->where('projects.token', '=', $token)
            ->where('project_users.id_user', '=', $user_id)
            ->get('mysql_db_name');

        if ($get_db_name) {
            $db_name = $get_db_name[0]->mysql_db_name;
            $update_status = DB::table($db_name . '.feeds')
            ->where('id_project', $token)
                ->where('id_feed', $feed_id)
                ->update([
                    'status'  =>  $request->status
                ]);

            dd($update_status);

            return response()->json($update_status, 200);
        }
```

That `dd` is returning me 0 instead of 1, Can you tell me why?

Comment: You're doing `->update(['status' => $request->status'])`, but is `status` _actually changing_? `->update()` can return `0` if A) it finds no rows to update, or B) the update doesn't change anything (i.e. if `status` is `active`, and you call `->update(['status' => 'active'])`, that will return `0`)

Comment: Also, do `DB::table($db_name . '.feeds')->where('id_project', $token)->where('id_feed', $feed_id)->exists()` (or `->count()`) to see if there are any records found by your query.

Comment: this `$request->status` is giving me either `true` or `false` value. And on that `status` column I set the data type as `tinyint(4)`. Does it the issue?

Comment: Also also, `->get('mysql_db_name');` followed by `$get_db_name[0]->mysql_db_name;` is kinda silly; just do `->first()`, then `$get_db_name->mysql_db_name`. `get()` returns multiple rows, but you're only using the first one, so use `->first()`

Comment: No idea; I've never used the `tinyint(4)` datatype. Can you update it using `0` or `1` via your Command Line (or SQL tool)?

Comment: Well, If I manually enter the `'status'  =>  0` Or `'status'  =>  1` then its updatng.

Comment: I can see that `$request->status` value is either `NULL` or `true` value. So, this might be an issue, right?

Comment: yes $request->status = 0 then it is update

Comment: `null` would be an issue if that column doesn't allow `null`. Also, I can't answer that; you have your database in front of you; try with `null`, and if it doesn't work, then there's your answer 

Comment: you add a condition if($request->status == null){   $request->status = 0 }

Comment: @UmerFayyaz Or, more simply, `$request->input('status', false)`; you don't need an `if()` statement to handle if a `$request` variable is `null`; you pass a 2nd param to `input()` as a fallback.

Comment: Let me try with that.

Comment: I solve the issue. I was getting the wrong value. Anyways. Thanks a lot everyone :)